# Scala Map Integer to (Integer => Integer)

Tags: scala

How can I `map` over a List from 1 to 100 (inclusively) to make each item a Function1 that curries each element to partially apply `(itself * _)`.

I tried this:

```
scala> val xs: List[Integer => Integer] = List.range(1,101).map { x => _ * x }

<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => 
             x$1.$times(x))
       val xs: List[Integer => Integer] = List.range(1,101).map { x => _ * x }
```

Desired output:

```
val xs: List[Integer] = List[1,2,3,4, .., 100]
val desired: List[Integer => Integer] = List[(*1), (*2), ...]
```

Then, this would be expected too:

`desired.get(0).apply(2) = 2 // 1 * 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you exactly what you need to fix here: "Missing parameter type". Change `_ * x` to `(_: Integer) * x`.

Incidentally, is there some reason you're using `java.lang.Integer` here?  You probably mean `scala.Int`:

```
val fns: List[Int => Int] =
    List.range(1, 101).map{x => (_: Int) * x}
```

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I was using `java.lang.Integer` since I've been studying Learn You a Haskell and forgot `Int` in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**
The compiler can't infer the *type* of ''_''.
That is because there is no need for ''_'' to be a Integer, just because you used a List of Integers to create these functions.

With other words at this point it is not clear what kind of type should be bound to the free parameter of the partially applied function.

As stated before, this solution works for your case if the input will be Integers

```
(1 to 101) map ( x => x * (_:Int) )
```

**An example:**

```
val functions = (1 to 101) map ( x => x * (_:Int) )
```

This will work

```
functions map (_(2))
res13: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4 ...
```

This would fail:

```
functions map (_(2.5))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found   : Double(2.5)
required: Int
          functions map (_(2.5))
```